# Setting points in a d3.js Global Map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The main problem I have is that when I try to draw points inside the map, when creating the cx, and cy coordintes it appear as null, but If you check it, the patch, from my point of view, is correct.

```
    d3.json(meteorites, function(meteorite){
console.log("meteorite", meteorite.features);
svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(meteorite.features)
.enter()
 .append("circle")
.attr({
cx: function(d){ return projection(d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1])[0];},
 cy: function(d){ return projection(d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1])[1];},
 r: 5,
fill: "red"

});
```

And also If you prefer to see what I wrote here is the link to my codepen http://codepen.io/DiazPedroAbel/pen/bwoBZd

I have been trying aswell without the projection, but the result is the same, null but if I do a console.log() I got the result I am expecting. Probably I am misunderstanding something here, Is the first time I draw a map in d3.

Comment: `projection` [takes an array](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Projections.md#_projection) `projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]])`

Comment: I correct that part, but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like that you have some entries in the JSON file that do not contain the `geometry` object and the accompanying `geometry.coordinates` array, causing the script to fail. I suggest that you implement a basic filter when attaching `.data()`, to ensure that you are only processing nodes that have their geo coordinates defined, i.e. instead of simply having the following:

```
.data(meteorite.features)
```

…you can use `.filter()` to weed out entries from your array of objects that do not have the `geometry` object, or the `geometry.coordinates` array defined:

```
.data(meteorite.features.filter(function(d) {
  return d.geometry && d.geometry.coordinates;
}))
```

Refer to the [corrected CodePen example](http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/xEXLVO?editors=0010#0), with the following code block updated:

```
d3.json(meteorites, function(meteorite){
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(meteorite.features.filter(function(d) {
          return d.geometry && d.geometry.coordinates;
        }))
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr({
          cx: function(d){ return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];},
          cy: function(d){ return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1];},
          r: 5,
          fill: "red"
    });
});
```